# Role of rotation in Caeser Cipher using Java

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I understand Caesar Cipher from [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/ciphers/a/shift-cipher) and [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/), from both of these links, I understand the formula for encryption

```
Y = (X + K) mod 26
```

and for decryption

```
X= (Y - K) mod 26
```

But when I follow the code from **Data Structure and Algorithm in Java Goorich, Tamassia and Goldwasser book**, Code is below

```
public class CaeserCipher
{
protected char[] encoder = new char[26]   // Encryption array
protected char[] decoder = new char[26]   // Decryption array
public CaeserCipher (int rotation)
 {
  for (int k=0;k<26;k++)
  {
    encoder[k]= (char)('A' + (k + rotation) % 26);
    decoder[k]= (char)('A' + (k - rotation + 26) % 26);
  }
 }

public String encrypt(String message)
 {
   return transform(message,encoder);
 }
public String decrypt(String secret)
 {
   return transform(secret,decoder);
 }
private String transform(String original, char[] code)
 {
  char[] msg = original.toCharArray();
  for(int k = 0; k < msg.length; k++)
   if(Character.isUpperCase(msg[k]))
    {
     int j = msg[k] - 'A';
     msg[k] = code[j];
    }
  return new String(msg)
 }
public static void main (String[] args)
{
CaeserCipher cipher= new CaeserCipher(3);
System.out.println("Encryption code =" + new String(cipher.encoder));
System.out.println("Decryption code =" + new String(cipher.decoder));
String message = "THE EAGLE IS IN PLAY; MEET AT JOE'S.";
String coded = cipher.encrypt(message);
System.out.println("Secret: "+ coded);
String answer = cipher.decrypt(coded);
}}
```

I have 2 queries, 
1- Why we using rotation? and how it will work?
2- Why change in the formula? Why those other formula's not working here. Though the above code is only for capital letters because of Unicode.

Comment: `rotation` is the key (`k` in your original formulae). What's not clear?

Comment: why we using this 'A' ? why adding 26 in decrypt formula?

Comment: We're using `'A'` because it's the first character in the ASCII table (that is, we're transforming numbers 0-26 to printable letters). About the 26 I'll need to read a bit more thoroughly. Give me some minutes

Comment: I got it, to make the numbers positive we are doing +26, thanks you

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: There are two encrypt functions, please edit.